# How to store two different dateFormat strings into two variables

Tags: java, android, datetime, android-datepicker

I have an EditText on which click event I am showing the DatePicker Dialog Box and displaying the choosen date in **"MMMM dd, yyyy"** format i.e June 26, 1932 . **But I need to pass the date in the different format to the server**;  format which I need to pass is **"1932-06-26"** . Below is my code :

```
       {
    dateFormatter = new SimpleDateFormat("MMMM dd, yyyy", Locale.US);        
                birthDate = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.birthday);
                birthDate.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_NULL);
                setDateTimeField();
    }

private void setDateTimeField() {
        birthDate.setOnClickListener(this);
        Calendar newCalendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        birthDatePickerDialog = new DatePickerDialog(this, new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {

            public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth) {
                Calendar newDate = Calendar.getInstance();
                newDate.set(year, monthOfYear, dayOfMonth);
                birthDate.setText(dateFormatter.format(newDate.getTime()));
            }

        },newCalendar.get(Calendar.YEAR), newCalendar.get(Calendar.MONTH), newCalendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH));
    }
```

And for storing the date in different format, I am following below method :

```
 birthDate = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.birthday);
        SimpleDateFormat formatDate = new SimpleDateFormat("dd MMM yyyy",Locale.US);
        String output = formatDate.format(birthDate.getText().toString());
        Log.d(TAG,"FORMATED DATE IS   ::::: " + output);
```

But I am getting an j**ava.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Bad class: class java.lang.String** error.

Is it at all possible to display date in one format and store the date into different format?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
    String tmpDate = "June 26, 1932" ;
    String parsedDate = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd").format(new SimpleDateFormat("MMMM dd, yyyy").parse(tmpDate));
    Log.d(TAG,"FORMATED DATE IS   ::::: " + parsedDate);
```

Answer (score 2):

First you have to parse the string to a date and then you can format it:

This code should work:

```
birthDate = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.birthday);
SimpleDateFormat formatDate1 = new SimpleDateFormat("MMMM dd,yyyy",Locale.US);
SimpleDateFormat formatDate = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd",Locale.US);
String output = formatDate.format(formatDate1.parse(birthDate.getText().toString()));
```

Answer (score 1):

Below is the final answer which I tried and is working quite well. I created a function and returning the final output which I want.

```
private String formatDate() {
        birthDate = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.birthday);
        String outputFormat = null;
        SimpleDateFormat formatDate = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd",Locale.US);
        String inputFormatStr = "MMMM dd, yyyy";
        DateFormat inputDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat(inputFormatStr,Locale.US);
        Date inputDate = null;
        try{
            inputDate = inputDateFormat.parse(birthDate.getText().toString());
            if(birthDate!=null){
                outputFormat = formatDate.format(inputDate);
            }
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "exception occurred with details: "+e.toString());
        }
            return outputFormat;
    }
```